# PL SQL Remove HTML Encoding

Tags: html, oracle, plsql, encoding

I know you can remove HTML tags with a command such as this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(overview, '<.+?>')
```

But, some of the text has actual HTML encoding, where the application actually encoded things, like single quotes to be:  &#39 or ’

I'm assuming these are pretty standard.  Is there a way to remove them and replace them with the actual character, or am I stuck with REPLACE and listing them?

Many thanks!

Comment: The regular expression fails on the HTML `<p id="<>">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`utl_i18n.unescape_references()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_I18N.html#GUID-721DF8FD-2DBE-4CFD-BCDE-656242BD497E):

```
utl_i18n.unescape_reference(regexp_replace(overview, '<.+?>'))
```

As a demo:

```
-- sample data
with t (overview) as (
  select '<div><p>Some entities: &amp; &#39; &lt; &gt; to be handled </p></div>'
  from dual
)
select REGEXP_REPLACE(overview, '<.+?>') as result1,
  utl_i18n.unescape_reference(regexp_replace(overview, '<.+?>')) as result2
from t
```

gets

| RESULT1 | RESULT2 |
| --- | --- |
| Some entities: &amp; &#39; &lt; &gt; to be handled | Some entities: & ' < > to be handled |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f8d0fe129e142d575c2bcdb7261b62b6)

---

<sub>I'm not endorsing (or attacking) the notion of using regular expressions; that's [handled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/266304) and [refuted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/266304) and [discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252396/266304) elsewhere. I'm just addressing the part about encoded entities.</sub>

Comment: utl_i18n.unescape_reference appears to be working.   New feature for me......thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper XML parser:

```sql
with t (overview) as (
  SELECT '<div><p>Some entities: &amp; &#39; &lt; &gt; to be handled </p></div>' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><p>&lt;test&gt;</p></body></html>' from dual
)
SELECT x.*
FROM   t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(value) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS text
         FROM   XMLTABLE(
                  '//*'
                  PASSING XMLTYPE(t.overview)
                  COLUMNS
                    value CLOB PATH './text()'
                )
      ) x
```

Which outputs:

> | TEXT |
> | --- |
> | Some entities: & ' < > to be handled |
> | Test<test> |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1db35b50ee5fe323f0226625d075e456)*